# Trouble with JavaScript Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a tricky time getting this regular expression to work. The pattern I have so far is:

```
var dollarPattern = /^\d{1,}|\s\d/gi;

var matchedResults = new Array();
matchedResults = textValue.match(dollarPattern);
```

What I am hoping to achieve is using the example string "2 to 2.99 (63 items)", I want to check if it either starts with a digit, or if it contains a blankspace followed by a digit (in this case, both conditions are true). However, I keep getting a "matchedResults is null" error in Firefox (although it should have a length of 2).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks...

Comment: What else is going on around that code?

Comment: `{1,}` is equivalent to `+`. That makes it a bit shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is escaping.

```
// Please note that this works, but @Lekensteyn pointed out that this uses string literals
// Also, this will give you the first match(if exists) only.
alert("2 to 3.99 (63 items)".match("^\\d\|\\s\\d"));
```

OR

```
// This one will give you all possible matches
alert("2 to 3.99 (63 items)".match(/^\d|\s\d/g));
```

Comment: Do you understand RE's? There is no need to use string literals instead of regular expression literals.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Nope, not a 100%. I posted the answer because it worked. There is no "need" but that doesn't mean that it can't be used and it won't work if used, right? After your comment, I did search for Javascript RE basics and I have modified the answer. Anyway, thanks for my very first downvote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in Chrome, FF4, and IE8.

I get null when I puts quotes around the regex.

However, the output I get it "2, 2".